# Percentage points for W in Worsley (1979, JASA)

Tags: change-point

Worsley (1979 JASA) provided, in the only table of the paper, the percentage points for the W statistic for detecting a shift in the mean of a normal population. Unfortunately, the table shows percentage points for sample size (n) up to 50. Where can I find a table showing the percentage points for sample size larger than 50? Worsley wrote that the percentage points for larger n can be calculated using a recursion procedure of Hawkins (1977 JASA), but has someone performed the computations and provided a table?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an R package with values for $n=100$ and $\infty$.  You could probably get a reasonable approximation by other values by some kind of interpolation

```
> library(climtrends)
> data(Worsley.Likelihood.Ratio.Test.Critical.Values)
> Worsley.Likelihood.Ratio.Test.Critical.Values
    Q90% Q95% Q99% R90% R95% R99%
10  1.05 1.14 1.29 1.21 1.28 1.38
20  1.10 1.22 1.42 1.34 1.43 1.60
30  1.12 1.24 1.46 1.40 1.50 1.70
40  1.13 1.26 1.50 1.42 1.53 1.74
50  1.14 1.27 1.52 1.44 1.55 1.78
100 1.17 1.29 1.55 1.50 1.62 1.86
Inf 1.22 1.36 1.63 1.62 1.75 2.00
```